# Differential form conventions

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It seems to me that there are two conventions of defining (differential) $k$-forms, namely depending on whether the factor $1/k!$ is included in front of the alternating sum, so e.g. for $2$-forms one can either have
$$ dx \wedge dy = \frac{1}{2!} (dx \otimes dy - dy \otimes dx) \quad\text{or}\quad dx\wedge dy = dx \otimes dy - dy \otimes dx. $$
Depending on which of the two one chooses, the formula for wedge products between $k$-forms also changes of course.

I am more interested in the implications this choice has once one starts introducing (semi-Riemannian) inner products.
A metric $g$ on the manifold induces an inner product on $1$-forms - in coordinates $\langle dx^i, dx^j \rangle = g^{ij}$. This can be extended to higher order tensors simply by multiplying the products of the components, i.e. $\langle dx^{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes dx^{i_k}, dx^{j_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes dx^{j_k} \rangle =  g^{i_1 j_1} \cdots g^{i_kj_k}.$
Now, depending on which one of the two conventions for defining forms one chooses, we either have
$$ \langle dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}, dx^{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{j_k} \rangle = \frac{1}{k!} \det \langle dx^{i_a}, dx^{i_b}\rangle \quad \text{ or } \quad k! \det \langle dx^{i_a}, dx^{i_b}\rangle. $$
But I have often seen this also defined as
$$ \langle dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{i_k}, dx^{j_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^{j_k} \rangle = \det \langle dx^{i_a}, dx^{i_b}\rangle, $$
which if I understand correctly, one obtains if one instead uses $\langle dx^{i_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes dx^{i_k}, dx^{j_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes dx^{j_k} \rangle =  \frac{1}{k!} g^{i_1 j_1} \cdots g^{i_kj_k}$ and the second convention for defining forms stated above.

I am a bit confused about the importance of these choices. For example, it seems to me that these then also have different definitions of the Hodge star operator and consequently also the volume form. Does this affect integration on manifolds? E.g. is the volume of the unit $2$-sphere equal to $4\pi$ with respect to all these conventions? Is there anything else they affect?

Comment: This indeed is a confusing situation. I prefer a convention such that if $(e_1,e_2)$ is the dual basis to $(dx,dy)$, then $$ (dx\wedge dy)(e_1,e_2) = 1. $$ This implies that the normalization should be $$dx\wedge dy = dx\otimes dy - dy\otimes dx. $$

Comment: @Deane Sure, that seems reasonable. But is there any objective reason why one should prefer one convention over the other? For example, I could argue that the convention which uses the $1/k!$ normalization factor is better because the formula for the wedge product is simpler.

Comment: There's also the convention that forces: if $\{d x^1, \dots, d x^n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $T_p^*M$, then $\{d x^{i_1}\wedge \dotsm\wedge d x^{i_k}~:~ i_1 < \dots < i_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\Lambda^k T^*_pM$. To add to the confusion, I've seen the definition $dx \wedge dy = \frac1{\sqrt 2} (\dotsm)$.

Comment: @Keshav Wonderful... :')

Comment: Without normalization the integral $\int_S\,dx\wedge dy$ over a surface lying in the $x$-$y$-plane gives the surface area. I find this the best convention.

Comment: @KurtG. By "without normalization" you mean in the definition of forms, or in the definition of inner products between 2-forms?

Comment: I mean Deane's favourite convention. Likewise, $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ should not be normalized so that we directly get a volume, and so on.

Comment: I agree with Deane. Saying the volume of the unit cube is $1/k!$ is plain obnoxious. @KurtG: Your comment is incorrect: That does not give you the surface area of $S$; it gives you the area of its projection on the $xy$-plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin that is true for an arbitrary surface but I wrote that $S$ lies in the $x$-$y$-plane.

Comment: Oh, apologies. I saw the "over" and my brain thought surface lying over the $xy$-plane. For a region in the plane, I would not say *surface area*, just *area*. :)

Comment: Very well, I agree now that with Deane as well. I would be grateful if someone can post an answer so we can close this question.

Comment: @MSDG, I was going to say that my view is subjective. I like my way, because it seems to make my calculations easier to do and remember.